# Schools in Canada

Tags: data-request, education, canada

Is there a database of schools in Canada? Can you drop a link that would direct me to that database?

If this does not exist, would you by chance know if the provinces have such data for the schools under them?

I have searched and seen only BC and ON.

Comment: What level are you looking for? Public schools? Universities and colleges?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_schools_in_Canada (and its linked sources) and similar wikipedia pages do not suffice?

Comment: Can you list the datasets you have found for BC and ON?

Answer (score 2):

If you are by any chances affiliated to a Canadian university you get free access to DMTI POI data that includes public schools and universities.

All of this is located in the Scholar GeoPortal repository at http://geo2.scholarsportal.info/